# Code to update a file in regular intervals

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu, cdn

I am trying to build a sample network as follows:

I have 2 AWS Ubuntu instances (say A and B). I have a file in the home directory of both the instances. They are the same files.

Now, if I update the file in A, then automatically it should be updated in B as well.

Could you please let me know a way to do this with Python or shell?

PS : This file consists of just alphabets from A-Z and is just simply created using a nano editor.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: So, basically, I have a file in one system (A) and the same file in another system (B). Now, whenever that file on A changes, the file on B should change as well!

Comment: [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example) can observe file or folder and execute function when something change.

Comment: I did this using the following link where something very very similar is solved: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672106/checking-the-output-of-diff-command-using-shell-script/55672781#55672781

Answer (score 0):

have you thought about using something like AWS's EFS to just keep the file the same on both systems via a mount point?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs.html

Answer (score -1):

The solution was as follows:

```
if cmp -s main <(ssh -i /home/ubuntu/sai_key.pem ubuntu@w.x.y.z 'cat /home/ubuntu/c1')
then
    echo "Match!"
else
    echo "No match!"
    scp ...
fi
```

I did this using the following link where something very very similar is solved: [Checking the output of "diff" command using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672106/checking-the-output-of-diff-command-using-shell-script/55672781#55672781)